# Usage of "Prohibited" vs "Prevented" in a given sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is the following usage of "prohibit" correct?

> The disk crash prohibited me from saving the file.

I have an opinion, but want to hear what others think before I share it.

Comment: Probly not. _Prohibit_ usually refers to official forbiddance, and can be flouted, whereas _prevent_ is a [Neg-_if_ Predicate](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Predicatetypes.pdf), which entails the falsity of its complement. Hence, _They prohibited me from coming, but I showed up anyway_ is grammatical, but _*They prevented me from coming, but I showed up anyway_ is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *prohibit* an action is to lay down a rule that informs someone that they cannot perform that action.

To *prevent* the action is to actually stop it.

For example, I can put up a sign on a lawn that says "Walking on the grass is prohibited", but to actually prevent anyone from walking on the grass, I could put up a fence around it, *preventing* people from walking on the grass.

Answer (score 2):

*Prohibited* is used for when doing something is officially denied to you, whereas *prevent* is used for the careful measures you use or must have used to avoid a particular situation or happening. In the question asked by you, use of *prohibited* is grammatically correct, but using *prevented* sounds much better.

Comment: Please use proper capitalization in your answers, and refrain from textspeak, such as "u" for "you". (After all, this site is devoted to the serious study of English.)

Answer (score 1):

'Prohibited' suggests some kind of legal constraint, so it's probably not appropriate here.